# Script.newTrigger() returns the error "Unexpected error while getting the method or property create on object"

Tags: google-apps-script, gs-installable-triggers

When trying to create a time-based trigger, I get this error:

> "Unexpected error while getting the method or property create on object ScriptApp.ClockTriggerBuilder."

Here is the code:

```
function genTrigger(){
var triger = ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction").timeBased().everyHours(5).create(); 
}

function myFunction(){
//contains some code....
}
```

Comment: How are you receiving this error? Is this through the menu option "Run" -> "Test as add-on.." or "Run"->"Run function" or some other way. Additionally, is this run time V8 or V7?

Comment: @AustinHoag the run time is _V8_ and I got the error while running it programatically. Even I can run the same code by script without any trouble.

Comment: I have the same issue. May I know how you solve this problem ?

Comment: @Deno Problem not solved yet.....If you get any solution please let me know and if I get then I'll let you know.

Comment: Me too having the same problem. Googling this points to making sure that oauth is set correctly, however I'm getting this both with explicit oauth rules (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp) and with none set. I copied this from the manual, and "unexpected" is not very clear... maybe it's a bug on google side?

Comment: small note: I understand the callback will be invoked with 1 argument. Still doesn't solve it 'tho: I tried both with 0 and 1 arguments, same result.

Comment: Upon quick search on the Google issue tracker, this seems to be a bug on Google side:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153068450
Please upvote/leave a comment there so that it has more visibility: it's been more than a month!

Comment: @Bhupesh - please, clarify what context the issue happens in (I know it's a late response, but the issue seems unresolved still)? Does it happen in the editor or as an action callback in an Add-on? Also to correct Austin: there are only two runtimes for GAS: Rhino (Java) and V8

Comment: @Oleg: it definitely happens in a callback, but I think it also happens in the editor. I can try later. In the bug tracker link above there’s more information.

Comment: @MicheleDiCosmo - ah, so the last message in the tracter is yours then? Thanks for clarifying (it would also be nice to hear from Bhupesh or Deno to compare). Can you please, at the top of the callback, before the call to trigger builder, log the results of [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getauthorizationinfoauthmode) when you will be checking?

Comment: @MicheleDiCosmo yes it happens when callback, it works proper in editor

Comment: @Bhupesh - so you still experience the issue? Have you tried to log what I proposed in the comment above, btw?

Comment: @OlegValter I can confirm it does work in the editor, it doesn't from code. I tried to get the authInfo (didn't know that was a requirement for triggers), but still no luck: `getAuthorizationStatus()` returns `NOT_REQUIRED`.
And yes, the cake button guy in the google tracker is me.

Comment: @MicheleDiCosmo - thank you for checking! Well, this thing is buried in docs (I only happened to know it because of incremental OAuth). And since it returned as it should, `NOT_REQUIRED`, it is also of little help... Btw, what happens if you wrap the callback in `try...catch` and log the error? Sometimes error messages in GAS are more helpful if handled

Comment: And you know what, despite it is not explicit, I think the reason of the error is [this notice](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers#editor_add-on_trigger_types). One can conclude that Gmail add-ons can't use installable triggers at all. As a workaround - try deploying as a self-calling library (I once [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56364403/11407695) a question related to that) - if it works, then the problem is the Gmail Add-on deployment. I can't say about Bhupesh's situation, though

Comment: @MicheleDiCosmo  @OlegValter as you both know that this time trigger was working properly 3 months ago but now it is having issue, I think that google has changed some concept related to timeBased trigger in Gmail addon using appscript. It creates issue only when callback not in editor including its authScope  ```scriptApp.script```

Comment: @OlegValter the same error was caught in ```try...catch```

Comment: H @Bhupesh - yeah, you are probably right about an underlying change. As this only happens in the action callback, judging from the error message, it is a permission-related error, which is why I asked to check what `getAuthorizationStatus()` returns. Google's OAuth 2.0 flow behaves somewhat erratically as of recent, that's true...

Comment: Thanks @OlegValter for your reply. Yes, no more detail is captured with a try catch. I read your article and if I understand correctly your solution would install a trigger on the... library context, and not on the user context? My trigger needs to deal with GMail mails so I wonder if there's a way for an external library to keep the context / auth / etc... in the trigger callback

Comment: @MicheleDiCosmo - as far as I know the only context one has for triggers is the user context, so the triggers will always be installed on user's behalf. The library keeps the authorization context, the trick here is deploying *the same* script as a library. As the problem is with trying to run a sensitive action in the context of action response callback moving the creation of the trigger from it may at least solve the issue for you

Comment: Hey there. is this issue solved yet or not? Please let me know

Comment: @Bhupesh - somebody commented on the issue tracker that it is solved several days ago, but no official info from Google teams yet, so I would wait. Will test later, though. If you still have issues, comment there so as it is not accidentally closed as fixed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153068450

Comment: @OlegValter Thanks man for your updates. Can you do me a favour please.... can you please upvote my all comments on this post because I need 50 reputation to make comment on others post.

Comment: @Bhupesh - that won't do anything - only posts affect the reputation. That said, I upvoted the question (please don't ask to do that going forward, this is usually not well met) - this is a relevant issue that is, unfortunately, still unresolved.